# Cancel long-running Dapper Query

Tags: c#, dapper

We have a winforms application which uses Dapper for database reads.

In one form we have a (possible) long running query on a background thread.

The users want to be able to cancel the query, so i need access to the DbCommand Dapper creates and call Cancel on it, if it is running, from another thread.

What would be the best way of exposing this DbCommand from Dapper?

Comment: This is not currently exposed, and I can't think of any *easy* ways of adding it, short of passing in an interface which advertises an event... I'm assuming this particular example is the exception rather than the norm? Perhaps code *just this one* up manually?

Comment: I thought i finally got rid of the manual datareader stuff... Guess not. But still, I love Dapper.

Comment: if you have an particular ideas on this, I'm all ears ... but.... I can't see any *easy* way =

Comment: Well, i think about introducing an IQueryPipeline interface optional parameter which exposes the events needed for my purpose

Comment: @MarcGravell how about just allowing us to access it via an explicit cast? `((WrappedReader)reader).Cancel()` or similar.

Comment: I wonder if there has been any follow up to this.

Comment: We need this as well...

Answer (score 0):

It's hammer time. Break stuff.

```
using (var reader = connection.ExecuteReader(query)) {
```

....  now to cancel

```
var wrappedReaderType = typeof (Dapper.CommandDefinition)
                        .Assembly.GetType("Dapper.WrappedReader");
var field = wrappedReaderType
            .GetField("cmd", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
if (field != null)
{
    var command = field.GetValue(reader) as IDbCommand;
    if (command != null)
    {
        command.Cancel();
    }
}
```